# I am failing to make a succesful indent from adapter

Tags: android

I am setting this adapter for an RecyclerView, I am failing to make an indent from that adapter I don't know why can some body guide me what is going on here because I am not an expert in programming as well in this android.

Below is my Adapter class and Activity class.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
private String[] mDatasetname;
private Integer[] mexp;
private Context context;
public ToggleButton select;
Integer selectedcountint=0;
private Bitmap[] mpro;
private String[] mloc;
private String[] mobj;Context m;
private String[] mselected;
 public ArrayList<String> nselected = new ArrayList<>();



public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public CardView mCardView;
    public TextView mTextView;
    public TextView texp;
    public Button pdf;
    public ToggleButton select;
    public ImageView pro;

    public TextView loc;
    public View layout;
    Context context;
    private RecyclerView.ViewHolder s;

    public MyViewHolder(View v){

        super(v);


        mCardView = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_text);
       texp = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.setexp);
        pdf = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.moreinfo);
        select = (ToggleButton) v.findViewById(R.id.select);
        pro = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.setpropic);
        loc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.setlocation);

    }

    void bind(String name, Integer exp, String location, final Bitmap image, final String obj ) {
        mTextView.setText(name);

       texp.setText(String.valueOf(exp)+" yrs");
        pro.setImageBitmap(image);
        loc.setText(location);


        pdf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Dashboard.this, com.parse.starter.View.class);
                intent.putExtra("no", "6382551203");
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }


}

public MyAdapter(Context s,String[] myDataset,Integer[] exp,Bitmap[] pro,String[] loc,String[] obj){


    mDatasetname = myDataset;

    mexp=exp;
    mpro=pro;
    mloc=loc;

    mobj=obj;
    m=s;


}



@Override
public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){

    context=parent.getContext();

    View vs = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_item, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(vs);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position){


    holder.bind(mDatasetname[position],mexp[position],mloc[position],mpro[position],mobj[position]);

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() { return mDatasetname.length; }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

Instead of this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Dashboard.this, com.parse.starter.View.class);
intent.putExtra("no", "6382551203");
startActivity(intent);
```

Write like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Dashboard.this, (your_destination_class_name).class);
intent.putExtra("no", "6382551203");
startActivity(intent);
```

For Example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Dashboard.this, RegisterActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("no", "6382551203");
startActivity(intent);
```

If you're destination class name is View.class then change it to something else.

If the above method doesn't work,

Replace:

```
View vs = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_item, parent, false);
```

with:

```
View vs = LayoutInflater.from(m).inflate(R.layout.card_item, parent, false);
```

and try. Hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
  first make constructor, adapter wont work with out constructor, its a big miss please check

    holder.pdf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(context,YourIndentClassName.class);
                    intent.putExtra("no", "6382551203");
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your code with this:

```
pdf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, com.parse.starter.View.class/*should be a proper class name*/);
                intent.putExtra("no", "6382551203");
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
holder.pdf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context,YourIndentClassName.class);
                intent.putExtra("no", "6382551203");
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

**strong text**
 use this code in your onBindViewHolder method of RecyclerVieAdapter